# Upgrade from Opencv 2.3 to 2.4.2

Tags: opencv, android-ndk

I´m building an Android app using Opencv, It´s an old project, so I was using cygwin with ndk 6, I upgraded to ndk8b, and use only windows. I updated ADT to lasted version. Build .so target file it´s ok with Opencv 2.3, but when I change my GNU C/GNU C++ Path and Symbols to a Opencv2.4.2 directory and change my include of OpenCV.mk on Android.mk file, build failed.

The erros are:

```
/jni/scan_utils.cpp:44: undefined reference to `cvReleaseImage'
/jni/scan_utils.cpp:50: undefined reference to `cvLoadImage'
/jni/scan_utils.cpp:54: undefined reference to `cvCreateMat'
/jni/scan_utils.cpp:77: undefined reference to `cvGetPerspectiveTransform'
```

But if I click on function my CDT plugin on eclipse show me the reference.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Android.mk and Application.mk follow the instructions http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package_using_with_NDK.html

You probably did not change the lines about LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES, LOCAL_LDLIBS, LOCAL_LDFLAGS when you upgraded to 2.4.2.